# Реализация паттерна состояние

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код ниже подсчитывает из строки с символами количество очков по следующей схеме:

«Х» –  20 очков

«4/» -  15 очков

«34» – сумма 3+4=7

«-4» - сумма 0+4=4

Подсчет делится на 2 хода, и определенные комбинации дают определенные очки. Ранее подсчет у меня велся с помощью функции result_count, которая брала из get_score оба хода и высчитывала.

Теперь мне нужно реализовать с помощью паттерна состояние чтобы каждый ход рассчитывался отдельно. Я читал по нему информацию, но так до конца не пойму, как можно его применить в этом коде. Я создал класс, берущий список обоих ходов, в котором есть 2 метода, рассчитывающие отдельно 1 и 2 ход путем разбивки внутри себя двух значений. Но насколько я понимаю, это не та конструкция, должно быть реализовано какое-то переключение между методами, а не так чтобы они оба вызывались. Подскажите, что тут нужно изменить для правильного решения?

```
analysed_res = {}
total = 0
values = []


def get_score(game_result):
    global analysed_res, total
    analysed_res = {}
    total = 0
    frames = 0
    for _ in game_result:
        for key, value in enumerate(zip(game_result.replace('X', 'X-')[0::2], game_result.replace('X', 'X-')[1::2]),
                                    start=1):
            analysed_res[key] = value
    for number, analysed_value in analysed_res.items():
        frames += 1
        #result_count(analysed_value)
        values.append(analysed_value)


def result_count(analysed_value):
    global total
    if 'X' in analysed_value:
        total += 20
    elif '/' in analysed_value:
        total += 15
    elif '-' in analysed_value:
        total += 0
    else:
        total += int(analysed_value[0]) + int(analysed_value[1])
    return analysed_value


class Switcher:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.first_score = 0
        self.second_score = 0

    def first_move(self):
        for value in self.value:
            one = value[0]
            if one == 'X':
                self.first_score += 20
            elif one == '-' or value[1] == '/':
                pass
            else:
                self.first_score += int(one)


    def second_move(self):
        for value in self.value:
            two = value[1]
            if two == '/':
                self.second_score += 15
            elif two == '-':
                pass
            else:
                self.second_score += int(two)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = '123/XXXXXX--X'
    get_score(game_result=result)
    s = Switcher(values)
    s.first_move()
    s.second_move()
    print(s.first_score, s.second_score)
```

```
Всего 10 кеглей. Игра состоит из 10 фреймов. В одном фрейме до 2х бросков, цель - сбить все кегли.
Результаты фрейма записываются символами:
  «Х» – «strike», все 10 кеглей сбиты первым броском
  «<число>/», например «4/» - «spare», в первый бросок сбиты 4 кегли, во второй – остальные
  «<число><число>», например, «34» – в первый бросок сбито 3, во второй – 4 кегли.
  вместо <число> может стоять прочерк «-», например «-4» - ни одной кегли не было сбито за первый бросок
Результат игры – строка с записью результатов фреймов. Символов-разделителей между фреймами нет.
Например, для игры из 4 фреймов запись результатов может выглядеть так:
  «Х4/34-4»
Предлагается упрощенный способ подсчета количества очков:
  «Х» – strike всегда 20 очков
  «4/» - spare всегда 15 очков
  «34» – сумма 3+4=7
  «-4» - сумма 0+4=4
То есть для игры «Х4/34-4» сумма очков равна 20+15+7+4=46
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как реализовать паттерн состояние](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211641/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: @vp_arth указанный вами вопрос был удален, так что данный де-юре не является дубликатом.

Comment: Опишите алгоритм подсчёта очков подробнее. Что должно получиться из этой строки `123/XXXXXX--X`?

Comment: @EzikBro, сравните время удаления с временем комментария =)

Comment: @MiniMax я в конце вопроса дополнил подробными правилами подсчета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class State(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def strike(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def spare(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def count(element):
        if element == '-':
            return 0
        if element != '0':
            return int(element)


class Bowling:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = None
        self.move_counter = 0
        self.total_score = 0

    def change_state(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def char_state(self, element):
        if element == 'X':
            self.total_score += self.state.strike()
        elif element == '/':
            self.total_score += self.state.spare()
        elif element.isdigit() or element == '-':
            self.total_score += self.state.count(element)

    def split(self, game_result):
        frame = game_result[self.move_counter] + game_result[self.move_counter + 1] \
            if game_result[self.move_counter] != 'X' else game_result[self.move_counter]
        yield frame
        self.move_counter += 1 if len(frame) == 2 else 0

    def switch(self, game_result):
        while self.move_counter < len(game_result):
            frame_generation = self.split(game_result)
            for frame in frame_generation:
                if len(frame) == 1:
                    self.change_state(FirstMove())
                    self.char_state(frame[0])
                elif frame[1] == '/' and frame[0].isdigit() and frame[0] != '0':
                    self.change_state(SecondMove())
                    self.char_state(frame[1])
                else:
                    self.change_state(FirstMove())
                    self.char_state(frame[0])
                    self.change_state(SecondMove())
                    self.char_state(frame[1])
                self.move_counter += 1


class FirstMove(State):
    def strike(self):
        return 20

    def spare(self):
        pass


class SecondMove(State):
    def strike(self):
        pass

    def spare(self):
        return 15
```

Answer (score 5):

**Решение с использованием паттерна состояние**

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class State(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def throw(self, throw_result):
        pass

class First_attempt(State):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game

    def throw(self, throw_result):
        if throw_result == 'X':
            self.game.score += 20
        else:
            if throw_result.isdigit():
                self.game.first_attempt_points = int(throw_result)
                self.game.state = self.game.second_attempt
            elif throw_result == '-':
                self.game.state = self.game.second_attempt

class Second_attempt(State):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game

    def throw(self, throw_result):
        if throw_result == '/':
            self.game.score += 15
        elif throw_result.isdigit():
            self.game.score += self.game.first_attempt_points + int(throw_result)

        self.game.first_attempt_points = 0
        self.game.state = self.game.first_attempt

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_attempt = First_attempt(self)
        self.second_attempt = Second_attempt(self)

        self.score = 0
        self.first_attempt_points = 0

        self.state = self.first_attempt

    def throw(self, throw_result):
        self.state.throw(throw_result)
```

**Тестирование**

```
scores = [
            "X4/34-4",
            "123/XXXXXX--X"
        ]

for score in scores:
    game = Game()

    for throw_result in score:
        game.throw(throw_result)

    print(game.score)
```

**Результат**

```
46
158
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я еще перечитал документацию по состоянию сам паттерн подразумевает переключение между состояниями, для чего используется switch.  Можете на вашем коде привести пример, как можно сделать переключение между классами по расчету каждого броска и функцией из вопроса, которая считает все вместе(result_count)?

Comment: @викторинторинов 1) В паттерне "Состояние" `switch` не нужен - смысл этого паттерна как раз в том, чтобы по возможности избавиться от `if`-ов и `switch`-ей. В какой документации написано про `switch`? 2) В моём коде происходит и переключение, и подсчёт каждого броска.

Comment: @викторинторинов Гляньте [пример паттерна "Состояние" в википедии (на Python)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Python).

Answer (score 1):

Немного другой вариант.

```
class Score():
    score = 0
    index = 0
    strscore = ''
    
    @classmethod
    def add_score(cls, addscore):
        cls.score += addscore
        
    @classmethod
    def add_str_score(cls, sscore):
        cls.score = 0
        cls.index = 0
        cls.strscore = sscore
    
    @classmethod
    def inext(cls):
        cls.index += 1
        return cls.index
    
    @classmethod
    def idx(cls):
        return cls.index

class SecondSignScore():
    cc = Score()
    
    def __new__(cls, index, score):
        if index < len(cls.cc.strscore):
            if cls.cc.strscore[index] == '/':
                cls.cc.add_score(15)
                cls.cc.inext()
            else:
                sc = 0 if cls.cc.strscore[index] == '-' else int(cls.cc.strscore[index])
                cls.cc.inext()
                cls.cc.add_score(score + sc)
        return cls.cc.score
        
class FirstSignScore():
    cc = Score()
    
    def __new__(cls, index):
        if index < len(cls.cc.strscore):
            if cls.cc.strscore[index] == 'X':
                cls.cc.add_score(20)
                cls.cc.inext()
            else:
                sc = 0 if cls.cc.strscore[index] == '-' else int(cls.cc.strscore[index])                
                return SecondSignScore(cls.cc.inext(), sc)
        return cls.cc.score
```

Собственно вызов решения:

```
Score.add_str_score('123/XXXXXX--X')

res = 0

while Score.idx() < len(Score.strscore):
    res = FirstSignScore(Score.idx())

print(res)
```

Ответ ожидаемый. :)

Но всё же, лучше без классов и без паттерна State.

Хоть кто-то предложит и более простое решение, на мой взгляд и это довольно лакончино:

```
import re

def decode_score(score):
    f_score = re.sub(r'-', "0", score)
    f_score = re.sub(r'\d/', "/", f_score)
    x_score = re.findall(r'X', f_score)
    s_score = re.findall(r'/', f_score)
    d_score = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d', f_score)))
    return len(x_score) * 20 + len(s_score) * 15 + sum(d_score)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = '123/XXXXXX--X'
    
    print(decode_score(result))
```